# Remove characters after space in sql

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have two tables as shown below:

[image: Table1]
[image: Table2]

I would like to match these two columns i.e FIRST_NAME from table1 to FIRSTNAME from table2.

I tried with the below query but only could match Richard and not Kristin.

```
SELECT * FROM
table1 A 
 JOIN
table2 B 
ON 
LEFT(upper(A.FIRST_NAME)||' ', CHARINDEX(' ', upper(A.FIRST_NAME)) - 1)= 
LEFT(upper(B.FIRSTNAME)||' ', CHARINDEX(' ', upper(B.FIRSTNAME)) - 1)
```

Please suggest!

Comment: What do your left... calculations actually return? Split_Part might be cleaner/easier - `splitpart(a.first_name,' ',0)`.

Comment: @Andrew: splitpart worked for me .. It was actually split_part in snowflake. Thank you very much !

Comment: there is a general SQL rule of never use functions in your where's, and a ON is a WHERE, thus depending on how large your tables are, and how complex you join logic gets, that is can be cleaner to push the transforms into a CTE (or sub query) where you build the `clean_name`of both tables, then the hash join between those will be cleaner.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would add trim to make sure there's no whitespace preventing a match.

```
select * from A join B on
upper(trim(split(A.FIRST_NAME, ' ')[0]::string)) = upper(trim(split(B.FIRST_NAME, ' ')[0]::string))
```